# MySQL Parameters not adding values

Tags: c#, mysql, parameters

I am trying to get the row count of my accounts table so that I can login accounts but the MySQL parameters aren't adding the values.

Here is my code:

```
public int MyMethod(string username, string password)
{
    int count = 0;
    string query = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = '?user' AND password = '?pass' LIMIT 1;";

    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connector))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?user", username));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?pass", password));

        count = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

parameter place holder **should not be enclosed with single quotes** because it forces it to become a value and not a parameter anymore, try this,

```
public int MyMethod(string username, string password)
{
    int count = 0;
    string query = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = @user AND password = @pass LIMIT 1;";

    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connector))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@user", username));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@pass ", password));

        connector.Open(); // don't forget to open the connection
        count = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM accounts WHERE username = '?user' AND password = '?pass';
```

This will get you the number of records that have the specified username and password.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add parameters like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", username);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", password);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:    **@myVariable** instead **'?myVariable'** , **SELECT COUNT(*)** instead **SELECT ***

```
public int MyMethod(string username, string password)
{
  int count = 0;
  string query = "SELECT count(*) FROM accounts WHERE username = @user AND password = @pass LIMIT 1;";

   using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connector))
   {
      connector.Open(); 
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", username);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", password);       
      count = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
   }

   return count;
}
```